# Создание списка и добавление в него элементов

Tags: c#

Написан класс для организации вопроса, ответы в нем представлены в виде списка. Никак не выходит ввести список ответов в `List`.

Пример вопроса:

> Сколько программистов нужно, чтобы закрутить лампочку?
>
> 1. Один
> 2. Ни одного. Это аппаратная проблема, программисты их не решают
> 3. Много

Правильный ответ: 2

Как создать список ответов и добавить в него конкретные ответы?

```
Question Q1 = new Question("Сколько программистов нужно, чтобы закрутить лампочку?",
    /*объявление списка*/, 3);
```

Код класса:

```
public class Question
{
    string questionText; // вопрос
    List<string> answers; // список ответов
    int correctAnswerNumber; // номер правильного ответа

    public Question(string questionText, List<string> answers, int correctAnswerNumber)
    {
        this.questionText = questionText;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.correctAnswerNumber = correctAnswerNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Regent  Question Q1 = new Question("Сколько программистов нужно, чтобы закрутить лампочку?", /*как то объявить список*/ , 3);

Comment: @Regent Так и не выходит объявить вопрос полностью.

Comment: Что значит _не выходит объявить_? Очень сложно помочь по пространным фразам.

Comment: Меня только "переглючило" малость: должно было быть `List<string> questionAnswers = new List<string>();`

Comment: есть одно небольшое но: при данном построении ответы будут под одним и тем же номером, можно составить карту ответов:) я бы наверно попробовал хранить "хеш" правильного ответа и проверять его с выбранным ответом, в этом случае можно делать пересортировку ответов, все проблемы не решит но все же:)

Comment: @Bald56rus Вообще нужно сделать случайный выбор ответов из имеющихся. Имеется N, а выводит 2 + правильный. Пока не сообразил как, а только класс сделал организации.

Comment: @Matroskin добавил ответ на ваш вопрос в коментарии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создание `List` и добавление в него элементов:

```
List<string> questionAnswers = new List<string>() { "Один", "Ни одного", "Много" };
```

Альтернативный вариант через метод `.Add()`:

```
List<string> questionAnswers = new List<string>();
questionAnswers.Add("Один");
questionAnswers.Add("Ни одного");
questionAnswers.Add("Много");
```

Передача `questionAnswers` в конструктор `Question`:

```
Question Q1 = new Question("Сколько программистов нужно, чтобы закрутить лампочку?",
        questionAnswers, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Question
{
    //Идентификатор вопроса
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //Текст вопроса
    public string QuestionText {get;set;}
    //Хеш правильного ответа
    public string QuestionAnswer {get;set;}
}

public class Answer
{
    //Идентификатор ответа
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //Текст ответа
    public string AnswerText {get;set;}
}

//Вопрос-ответы
public QuestionAnswers
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int QuestionId {get;set;}
    public int AnswerId {get;set;}
}


List<Answer> listOfAnswer = new List<Answer>
{
    new Answer { AnswerText = "1"},
    new Answer { AnswerText = "2"},
    new Answer { AnswerText = "ниодного"}
}
```

я это представляю как то так: в таблице вопросов(Question) хранятся вопросы и хеши ответов на них, в таблице ответов(Answer) возможные варианты ответов, QuestionAnswers необходим для того что бы можно было вывести возможные варианты ответов(как на экзамене в гибдд: ответы похожи за небольшим исключением). формируем список Вопросов для него получаем возможные варианты ответов(правильный и два любых других) все это сортируем(ответы, вопросы) показываем пользователю.

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что у каждого вопроса будет излишнее количество ответов, скажем 5, и нужно всегда выводить случайные ( всего 3 ) варианты ответов и чтобы там присутствовал верный разумеется.

Comment: @Matroskin стоит попытаться решить задачу самостоятельно, и в случае возникновения конкретной проблемы задать **новый** вопрос с текущими кодом и проблемой.

Comment: @Matroskin да у каждого вопроса будут варианты неправильных ответов(связь Вопрос-Ответы) получаем два случайных неправильных ответа добавляем один правильный. можно обойтись и без этой связи